# MySQL failing on LEFT() with String 8863 characters long?

Tags: mysql, replace, mysql-8.0

Yet another fun and unexplained issue with MySQL. Code works perfectly fine with all other shorter strings (and has been for months), but when I try to following code on a String that's 8863 in length (designed to simply remove a comma as the last character), it just does nothing. No error or anything. Length is 8863 both before and after the execution (and note the RIGHT check works fine so the LEFT executes, it just fails to remove the last comma). As mentioned, ONLY happens with a very long string.

Anyone know what crazy limitations in MySQL I might be dealing with?

```
DECLARE var_sql_insert_1 text;

IF (RIGHT(var_sql_insert_1, 1) = ',') THEN
    SET var_sql_insert_1 = LEFT(var_sql_insert_1, LENGTH(var_sql_insert_1) - 1);
END IF;
```

Comment: What MySQL version you have? In MySQL 8 you can use  REGEXP_REPLACE(var_sql_insert_1, ',$', '');

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev 8.0.18. The problem is I need to replace only the last comma, not other commas within the string.

Comment: This is exactly what will do the code. The pattern ',$' mean last comma because the $ sign is mark end of string. Look solution here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2fc0e959490e357927dcc76293e8657a

Answer (score 1):

So the issue is I was using LENGTH which was returning the length in BYTES vs. CHAR_LENGTH which returns the length in characters. Sadly, with all the other languages I've used, the default LENGTH value was character and they BYTE_LENGTH was specifically designed to be byte. For MySQL it appears the reverse is true. Doesn't make much sense for a system that's mainly used to store and manipulate TEXT rather than byte data...

Answer (score 0):

Since MySQl 8 where introduced function REGEXP_REPLACE you can use next solution:

```
SET var_sql_insert_1 = REGEXP_REPLACE(var_sql_insert_1, ',$', '');
```

The pattern ',$' mean last comma before end of line $

[Look the example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=099a292961764ab3b112bba21d79bfef)